# Show regular price along with discounted price in WooCommerce when assigning price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using a function to put my entire store on sale for 15% off. It works great but it changes all the pricing the the loops and the product page just to the new 15% off price. How can I set the sale price but also show the regular price too so I can then cross out the regular price with CSS.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'assign_tier_pricing', 90, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'assign_tier_pricing', 90, 2 );
function assign_tier_pricing( $price, $product ) {
if ( $product->is_type('simple') ) { 
    $price *= 0.85; // Set all prices for simple products to 50% off.    
}  
return $price; 
}
```

I would like to also return the regular price in a span so I can style it and cross it out so customers can see the normal price along with the sale price

So also return `<span class="regular-price">Display regular price</span>` then the new sale price right next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `is_on_sale()` to check https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product.html#method_is_on_sale

```
if ( $product->is_type('simple') && is_on_sale () )
```

or

```
if ( $product->is_type('simple') && ! is_on_sale () )
```

For ! Not on sale